# Обращение к пустой ячейке. OpenXML. Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

Хочу в пустую ячейку записать значение таким образом:

```
        // i строка из таблицы
        TableRow row = table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(i);
        // j ячейка из строки
        TableCell cell = row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(j);

        Paragraph paragraph = cell.Elements<Paragraph>().First();
        Run run = paragraph.Elements<Run>().FirstOrDefault();

        Text text = run.Elements<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
        //вставляем текст в ячейку
        text.Text = data;
```

Ругается на строчку:

```
        Text text = run.Elements<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
```

"В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект." (run=null)
Если использовать:

```
        Run run = paragraph.Elements<Run>().First();
```

То ругается на эту же строчку со словами "Последовательность не содержит элементов"...

Как можно выйти из такой ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменил

```
    Paragraph paragraph = cell.Elements<Paragraph>().First();
    Run run = paragraph.Elements<Run>().FirstOrDefault();
    Text text = run.Elements<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
    text.Text = data;
```

На

```
    cell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(data))));
```

Стало работать